# Minimize edges of a directed unweighted graph

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

I need to find an algorithm to find a sub-graph $G'=(V, E')$ of a directed unweighted graph $G = (V, E)$ where for all $(u, v)\in E$ there exists a path in $G'$ from $u$ to $v$ and the size of $E'$ is minimal.

This is not an MST (or arborescence) problem since we care every vertex as a root hence Edmond's algorithm does not work.

I am clueless at this point. At least a hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can formulate this as a mixed integer linear programming problem with nonnegative network flow variables $x_{i,j}^{u,v}$ and binary network design variables $y_{i,j}$. The problem is to minimize $\sum\limits_{(i,j)\in E} y_{i,j}$ subject to:
\begin{align}
\sum_{(i,j)\in E} x_{i,j}^{u,v} - \sum_{(j,i)\in E} x_{j,i}^{u,v}
&=
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if $i=u$}\\
-1 &\text{if $i=v$}\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
&&\text{for $i \in V$ and $(u,v)\in E$} \tag1
\\ 
x_{i,j}^{u,v}&\le (|V|-1)y_{i,j}
&&\text{for $(i,j)\in E$ and $(u,v)\in E$} \tag2
\end{align}
Flow balance constraints $(1)$ yield a path from $u$ to $v$, and big-M constraints $(2)$ enforce $x_{i,j}^{u,v}>0 \implies y_{i,j} = 1$.

---

An alternative approach to the compact $O(|E|^2)$ formulation above is a minimum $u$-$v$ cut-based formulation.  The idea is that every feasible solution must contain an arc from every $u$-$v$ cut $(S,V\setminus S)$. The problem is to minimize $\sum\limits_{(i,j)\in E} y_{i,j}$ subject to:
$$
\sum_{(i,j)\in (S,V \setminus S)} y_{i,j} \ge 1 \quad \text{for $(u,v)\in E$ and $S\subset V$ such that $u\in S$ and $v\in V \setminus S$} 
$$
Here, the constraints should be generated dynamically as they are violated.